# Remove Words From String based on word length in php

Tags: php, string

I want to remove words in a string that are longer than 2 letters. For example:

```
$string = "tx texas al alabama ca california";
```

I want to remove those words that have more than two characters so output would be like:
    $output = "tx al ca";

Comment: preg replace with [a-z]{3,} perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

```
echo preg_replace('/[a-z]{3,}/','',$string);
```

Comment: Much simpler than mine, if your actual data is different from your example just make sure it still matches that regex expression (ex. if it has numbers). +1

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, but you could just explode the string with space as a delimiter, loop through it, and create a new array and push words to it if the length is less than 2:

```
$string = "tx texas al alabama ca california";
$words = explode(' ', $string);

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if(strlen($word) <= 2) {
        $result[] = $word; // push word into result array
    }
}

$output = implode(' ', $result); // re-create the string
```

Output:

```
tx al ca
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/oJHKfBba)